# Have a gas water heater the tank has a leak have to shut off main valve to house is it safe to turn off gas to water tank

Tags: plumbing, natural-gas

Have a gas operated water heater/tank the tank is leaking itself I have to shut off Main water about the house should I turn off the gas supply to the water tank?

Comment: Yes, you should

Answer (score 3):

##### TURN OFF THE GAS

A combustion appliance should never be running in an unloaded situation except for testing purposes. Doing so can lead to additional damage to the appliance and possibly damage to your house.

Answer (score 0):

With the main water off, it would be a good time to add shut off valves to the tank.

You then will be able to turn on the main water for the house again.

Comment: My plumber did that when replacing my gas water heater last year. I heard water running. Went around the house and found the water heater leaking **a lot**. Fortunately, it is close to, and the floor slopes down to, a floor drain. Turned off the main water for the house (which previous plumber did many years ago because original shutoff doesn't work any more...) Eventually got a plumber (not as easy as it should be - I think there were a lot of pandemic-fueled retirements around here) and plumber installed new water heater with shutoff valves, expansion tank and all the other modern things.